# AJAX JQuery sending two XHR

Tags: php, jquery, global-variables

I want to send to php script a photo and four numeric values (variables). I'm doing it using JQuery AJAX. I must use two XHR objects, because sending files ruquire particular settings which are different than settings used to sending text - data. Here is relevant JS code:

```
//sending a photo
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {alert (data);}
    });



//sending variables
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        data: {
            x1: x1,
            y1: y1,
            x2: x2,
            y2: y2
        },
        success: function(data) {alert(data)}
    });
```

x1, x2, y3, y4 are variables which were set. 
Data are sending properly - confirmed by firebug.

Now, some PHP code:

```
<?php


$x1 = $_GET['x1'];
$y1 = $_GET['y1'];
$x2 = $_GET['x2'];
$y2 = $_GET['y2'];

$file= $_FILES['file'];

var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($file);
?>
```

And here is my problem. var_dump($file) gives desirable result, but variables $x1, $x2, $y1, $y2 are empty. XHR object with photo erases content of $_GET array. When I send these XHR objects to two different scripts everything is in order, var_dumps display right content of $_GET and $_FILES arrays.

I want have photo and variables in one php script. Variables are coordinates which are needed to crop some fragment of photo. Is it possible in any way?

Regards.

Comment: can you tell me what is the value of your data variable your are sending in your first ?

Comment: Data variable is a photo, it is a FormatData object

Comment: why you don't send the photo and the other variables as a serialized form. you place your x1, x2 ... in hidden fields and send the all with one ajax post query, thus you won't need to have 2 xhr !

Comment: You are right! I didn't think about it.
        `var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', files[files.length-1]);
  data.append('coordinates', $('#form').serialize());
`

I added the last line, and everything is working now! Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: Write your solution as an answer ! that may help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mansoulx has written in comment I've put photo (data variable) and variables (x1, x2, y1, y2 variables) in the same FormData object:

```
var data = new FormData();  
data.append('file', files[files.length-1]);
data.append('coordinates', $('#form').serialize());
```

and I'm sending data variable using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "upload.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {alert (data);}
});
```

Everything works, problem solved :)